# USB boot option on Grub Customizer?

Tags: grub2, usb

I want to add a boot option on Grub Customizer that boots to a USB flash drive?

For reference: [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).

Comment: Grub Customizer is a tool that sets up GRUB menu. Whatever manually you do, the Grub Customizer does it automatically. For example, you give the command `sudo update-grub` in order to build GRUB menu. The GUI tool also does the same automatically i.e., internally calling same command. Your question (that is what I understood) is : **"You want to add a boot option on Grub Customizer that boots to a USB flash drive?"**.  i.e. you want to put `bootable USB stick` directly into GRUB menu. Do you think you can do it manually using commands? If you can, then Grub Customizer can also do.

Answer (score 0):

## How GRUB2 works?

**GRUB2 works like this:** `/etc/default/grub` contains `customization` whereas `/etc/grub.d/` scripts contain GRUB menu information and operating system boot scripts. When the `sudo update-grub` command is run, it reads the contents of the `grub` file and the `grub.d` scripts and creates the `grub.cfg` file.

That's all. To change the `grub.cfg` file, you need to edit the `grub` file or the scripts under `grub.d.` Scripts are meant to be executed. This means that they have the execute bit turned `on`. If you turn the execute bit `off`, they will not run.

## Grub Customizer (Answer to the post)

Grub Customizer is a tool whose primary task is to set up GRUB menu among other things. Whatever manually you do, the Grub Customizer does it automatically. For example, you give the command `sudo update-grub` in order to build GRUB menu. The GUI tool also does the same automatically i.e., internally calling same command. Your question (this is what I understood) is : **"You want to add a boot option on Grub Customizer that boots to a USB flash drive?"**.

> You want to put **bootable USB stick** directly into GRUB menu i.e  **bootable USB** should appear as an entry in GRUB menu. Do you think you can do it manually using terminal commands? If you can, then Grub Customizer can also do.

**Note:** You can reach `GRUB menu` by pressing `shift` key while system booting.

## BIOS Setup Screen

You can easily make a `bootable USB stick` to appear in `BIOS setup screen` by inserting the device into `USB` port and select to boot the same by setting it up top priority among other bootloaders.

**Note:** You can reach `BIOS setup screen` by pressing `del` key while system booting.

## How to install Grub Customizer?

**Grub Customizer** is a graphical interface to configure the grub2. The application allows the user to add, remove, freeze, rename and reorder boot menu items.
Open a terminal and run following commands one by one:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

[image]
`Figure: Grub Customizer Main Window`

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire post here: [GRUB2 New menu entry pointing to USB drive](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/grub2-new-menu-entry-pointing-to-usb-drive-4175582347/)

This is how they set it up:

> My menu entry in `40_custom`
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> menuentry "Boot Kali Live from USB Drive"{
>     insmod chain
>     search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root EDCE-911D
>     chainloader ($root)/efi/boot/bootx64.efi
> }
> ```

After setting up a custom entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file remember to run `sudo update-grub`.